# Jquery Submitting a form does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I'm trying to submit a HTML form with submit() method of jQuery.

I'm registering a submitHandler for checking the formdata. IF check fails, the User can choose in a dialogue, whether he want to continue or cancel. On Continuing I deregister my Checkeventhandler and call submit() on the form, but nothing happens.

Here's my coding:

```
    <form action="test.php" id="summary_01" method="post">

</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#summary_01').on('submit', function(e){
         var result = check();
         if (!result) {
           e.preventDefault();
         }
         return result;
      });
    });

    function check() {
        var result = false;
        // do some Checks, setting result= true, if OK

        if(!result) {
            $( "#dialog-message" ).dialog({
                 modal: true,
                 resize : true,
                 width : 'auto',
                 buttons: {
                   Ok: function() { //Sending, despite check failed

                     $('#summary_01').unbind('submit'); //remove checkingForm Eventhandler
                     $('#summary_01').submit();
                     $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                   },
                   Cancel : function() {
                     $( this ).dialog( "close" );

                   }
                }
            });
        }
        return result;
    }
 </script>
```

I think the problem is e.preventDefault() but the dialogue call is asynchronous and therefore I prevent submitting until the user have chosen to continue or cancel.

Maybe you can help me. Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: can you try this:      $('#form01').submit( function(e){

Comment: different ids? $('#summary_01') and $('#form01')

Comment: You would technically be creating an endless loop if you were doing your close before your `$('#summary_01').submit();` youre submit isn't getting through because every time you submit youre running your preventDefault.  The way you have it set up currently you are popping a second dialog right before you close two of them

Comment: no I'm not getting in an endless loop, because i'm unbinding the submit eventhandler with  $('#summary_01').unbind('submit'); this works already

Comment: Is there even a `#summary_01` form?

Comment: sorry there's just one form with id = summary_01. I'll change this in  my code

Answer (score 1):

Call native `submit` function. In your code you have also other form id. Should be `#form01`.

```
$('#form01').off('submit');
$('#form01').get(0).submit();
```

Comment: Hi Thank for your reply. Unfortunately this also works not for me. Nothing happens then.

Comment: @user1829716 Do you have any `type="submit"`  input/button in form?

Comment: yes I have a send input with type submit. DOo I have to call submit() on this button?